# Dirty HTML or dirty jQuery for passing variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to pass variables to jQuery. There are two different approach as I see:

**clean HTML, dirty jQuery:**

```
<div class="itemContainer" data-id="1">
  Item information
  <input type="button" class="rename">
  <input type="button" class="delete">
</div>

$('.rename').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).parent().attr('data-id');
});
$('.delete').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).parent().attr('data-id');
});
```

PROs:
clean, not redundant HTML,

CONS:
not so clean jQuery,
if the DOM structure changes, its hard to detect the errors, and it has to be fixed at 2 places

**clean jQuery, dirty HTML:**

```
<div class="itemContainer">
  Item information
  <input type="button" class="rename" data-id="1">
  <input type="button" class="delete" data-id="1">
</div>

$('.rename').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
});
$('.delete').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
});
```

PROs:
clean jQuery,
works even DOM structure changes

CONS:
not so clean, redundant HTML,

which one would you prefer to use?

Comment: Definitely the first HTML structure, but use `$(this).closest('.itemContainer')` and share the code between the two handlers if appropriate.

Comment: if HTML structure is not fixed then it is better to use 2nd code , correct data is more important, you can go with code redundancy

Comment: @ACT possibly, but in this case both is still easily possible.

Answer (score 2):

Your first HTML structure is the better implementation as it avoids repetition of the same `data-id` attribute.

With regard to the jQuery, you can use a single event handler by separating the selectors with a comma (`,`), and you can use `closest()` to find the required parent element. This is more robust as you can then change the HTML structure within that parent however you require and it will not break the JS logic, so long as the clicked element is still a child node. Finally, note that you should use `data()` to get/set data attributes where possible, not `attr()`. Try this:

```js
$('.rename, .delete').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).closest('.itemContainer').data('id');
  console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="itemContainer" data-id="1"> Item information
  <input type="button" class="rename" value="Rename" />
  <input type="button" class="delete" value="Delete" />
</div>
<div class="itemContainer" data-id="99"> Item information
  <p>
    Extra information...
    <div class="another-child">
      <input type="button" class="rename" value="Rename" />
      <input type="button" class="delete" value="Delete" />
    </div>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the selectors you want to add the listener to *together* in the selector string you use to add a `.click` listener to (separated by commas), and you don't need to repeat yourself at all:

```js
$('.rename, .delete').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).parent().attr('data-id');
  console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="itemContainer" data-id="1">
  Item information
  <input type="button" class="rename">
  <input type="button" class="delete">
</div>
<div class="itemContainer" data-id="2">
  Item information
  <input type="button" class="rename">
  <input type="button" class="delete">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the `click` event for both the element using `Multiple Selector`. You can specify any number of selectors to combine into a single result. This multiple expression combinator is an efficient way to select disparate elements.

**clean jQuery, Clean HTML:**

```js
$('.rename, .delete').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).parent().attr('data-id');
    console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="itemContainer" data-id="1">
  Item information
  <input type="button" class="rename">
  <input type="button" class="delete">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [event delegation](https://gomakethings.com/why-event-delegation-is-a-better-way-to-listen-for-events-in-vanilla-js/) and a single data-attribute. You don't need jQuery for it. Added a button for restructuring the DOM to demonstrate that the handler keeps working after it.

```js
(() => {
  const evtHandler = evt => {
    const origin = evt.target;
    console.clear();
    if (origin.id === "redoDOM") { return restructure(); }
    if (origin.parentNode.classList.contains("itemContainer")) {
       console.log(`${origin.classList} data-id: ${origin.parentNode.dataset.id}`);
    }
  };
  document.addEventListener("click", evtHandler);
    
  function restructure() {
    if (!document.querySelector("#BttnContainer")) {
      let container = document.createElement("div");
      container.id = "BttnContainer";
      container.innerHTML = `
        <p>
          div.itemContainer elements are wrapped. 
          Check if the button handler still works
        </p>`;
      Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".itemContainer"))
       .forEach(v => container.appendChild(v));
      document.body.insertBefore(container, document.body.firstChild);
    } else {
      console.log("Already wrapped");
    }
  }
})();
```

```css
#BttnContainer {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<p>Click buttons to show data-id value of the surrounding element</p>

<div class="itemContainer" data-id="1">
  Item information (1)
  <button class="rename">rename</button>
  <button class="delete">delete</button>
</div>

<div class="itemContainer" data-id="2">
  Item information (2)
  <button class="rename">rename</button>
  <button class="delete">delete</button>
</div>

<p>
  Click to wrap buttons in a new element
  <button id="redoDOM">Restructure</button>
</p>
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't cover the OPs point about the DOM changing, though.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It depends. OP is not clear about how the DOM exactly would/could change. It would not work when the change involved `.itemContainer` being robbed of its `data-attribute`, or if buttons were moved outside the container.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan To accompany my previous statement I added some code to the snippet